# How to fetch only unread emails and set as read after viewing using IMAP?

Tags: email, imap, inbox, php-imap

Currently I'm using https://github.com/Eden-PHP/Mail (A PHP library to fetch inbox).

As per documentation, I'm not able to fetch unread emails.

My requirement is to fetch unread emails, after processing I want to update it as read!.

Comment: From their docs, i can see that it has a search function:

    $emails = $imap->search(array('UNSEEN'));
https://github.com/Eden-PHP/Mail#searching

Comment: They didn't mention where to call the function `$imap->search(array('UNSEEN')); `

Comment: I don't understand your last comment...

Comment: Updated, please have a look

Comment: You need to connect first: `$imap = new Imap($host,$user,$pass,$port = null, $ssl = false, $tls = false);` then call the `search()` function

Comment: Thanx! Search I'm able to use now! Now, how to set the email as read?

Comment: You should probably read RFC3501 so you understand how IMAP works, then you'll know how to use the library.  Presumably you want to use a function named `store` or similar, to change the flags.